# How can i restore the previous version of apk?

Tags: android, sql, websocket

I have an online app that WebSocket traffic I could easily read before the last update. In the sockets were the `question :{} answer1:{} answer2:{} answer3:{}` and after every answer:{} was the `bool` `true` or `false`, now they updated the app, and the WebSockets are the same but the `bools` `true` or `false` after answer:{} are missing. Can I restore somehow the previous version of the app by decompiling/recompiling it, and how to find the method or class what are hiding the `bools` `true` or `false`? Thanks in advance for your advice ;)

Comment: have you published your apk on google play?

Comment: yeah it's published on google play

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Console has all the previous version apks saved on their server.

1. Select your app
2. Select **Release Management> App Releases**
3. Select **Production Track> Manage**
4. Expand **Release History**.
5. Here you can see a list of all your previous apks,
6. Download any apk clicking the download button.

Comment: thx,but it is an online game directly connected and real time updated on a server,i tried before to launch it but it requires the newest version